# what is the difference between 'approve' and 'approbate'?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Could you explain difference between them such as usage?
In my dictionary, both have almost the same meaning.
I cannot understand exactly.

Comment: A very short answer: just don't use "approbate".  [It's a very rare word](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=approve%2Capprobate&year_start=1916&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Capprove%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capprobate%3B%2Cc0) and a lot of people won't understand what it means.

Comment: @stangdon: Quite. As I expected, searching Google Books for [**approbation sic**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22approbation+sic%22) turns up several instances where **[sic]** is included because the writer is citing someone else's incorrect use of **approbation** (where they probably should have used **opprobrium**).

Comment: As well as "rare", http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/approbate gives it as "US". I've never seen the verb "approbate" in British English, though the noun "approbation" is used (but only in a very formal context)

Comment: For a learner, the difference is that "approve" is an actual word while "approbate" is a rare technical term.

Answer (score 10):

*Approbate* means "to officially authorize" while *approve* means "agree or accept". *Approbate* is very formal and rather uncommon, and is usually used in official contexts such as political proceedings. Additionally, *approbate* refers more to the **action of approving** whereas *approve* connotes an **attitude or sentiment**, especially a moral judgment. *Approve* can also be used in context to mean "officially approve".

Examples:

> "I don't approve of such revealing clothing."
>
> "The chairman approbated our request."
>
> "This order needs to be approved by a judge before it can be carried out."

Comment: +1 for highlighting the distinction between the action and the sentiment.  "Approve" can be the action, but "approbate" is always the action.

Answer (score 2):

**Approbate** is more formal than **approve**.  In addition, its definition is more specific, describing an *official* approval.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the word "approbate" so I might be missing some of the nuances. As far as I can tell, they mean the same thing, but approbate is far more formal.

For example, I might approve of a new law, but that doesn't mean it is any more or less likely to become a law. But if the government "approbates" a new law, this new law is now legally and formally approved and is the law.

As for usage, I would recommend almost always using approve. You can use "approve" anywhere you could use "approbate" but definitely not the other way around. For example:

> I'm DJMcMayhem, and I approbate this message.

Sounds very strange. I would also recommend "approve" since it's a much more common word.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, they both have pretty much the same meaning. They have come, via different routes, from the latin word probere, meaning to test. Approbate is slightly more official in meaning, and many english speakers would have to look it up in the dictionary to be sure of the meaning. Firefox spell checker isn't to sure about it either :-). If you want to be understood, I would stick to approve.

It's worth noting that the expression "approve of" has a slightly different meaning. Here are some examples:

```
The government approved the new construction project.
The government approbated the new visa requirements.
```

Governments are involved, they have made a decision: something *very important* is about to happen.

```
My boss approved my expenses
```

This is only a small decision, but something is still going to happen as a result of it.

```
He approved of her taste in music.
```

He has no control over her taste in music, nothing will happen as a result of his approval, but he likes the kind of music she likes.